# How can I databind a control and object and modify the data as it passes through?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, data-binding, integer

**e.g.**:

- I have a `TextBox` named `milliseconds`
- I have a custom object named `myobject` of my class with variable `public int ms { get; set; }`
- so `myobject.ms` is what I want to change on input

However, the variable `milliseconds.Text` is a string, while the variable in `myobject` is an int

So when I try adding the databinding like so:

`milliseconds.DataBindings.Add("Text", myobject, "ms");` it produces a `System.ArgumentException` (I run the code multiple times)

Is there a way of changing the `milliseconds.Text` databinding to an into halfway through? (due to the incongruence between the string and the int)

Comment: `it produces a System.ArgumentException of course.`  Of course, it shouldn't.  Post the code you are using, not examples.

Comment: That is the code i'm using right now...

Comment: Is myobject a variable or a class?

Comment: myobject is a class, dataBindings produces an error when I run it twice after each other

Comment: It needs to be a variable: `myobject obj = new myobject();`  Now you use the obj for your databinding.

Comment: I understand that, `myobject` is already `listing myobject = new listing();` in my case

Comment: My question is how to parse the string from ms.text to an int to change the object variable

Comment: You need to post the code that produces the ArgumentException error.

Comment: As repeated, it's the above code - as a matter of fact, the code is not of importance as i'm not asking 'what is this error' but asking `how could I do the equivalent of this` and this is what i've tried?

Comment: When you use data binding, data conversion to target type will be done using data binding and it doesn't need any manual type conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind that property of your object to `Text` property of `TextBox`:

```
YourTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", 
    yourObjectInstance, "PropertyOfYourObject", true, 
    System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Data conversion to target type will be done using data binding and it doesn't need any manual type conversion.